# Should I use indexing on these type of attributes

Tags: sql, indexing

One certain tables I have an integer 'IsDeleted' field which defaults to 0.
This field basically flags a row as begin deleted or not. Now when querying I would specify to fetch records based on whether or not this flag has been set.

Would it be worthwhile to set an index on this attribute?

Comment: A good index usually has to be very **selective**, e.g. out of a given set of data, extract 2-5% of the data rows. If your `IsDeleted` flag matches that criteria - then yes, you could index it and see benefits. If you have 20%, 30%, 50% of deleted rows, then no, most likely, indexing won't help at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there will be much more deleted records than live (or vise versa), then querying for the least used type will benefit from the index.

Say, if `1%` of the records are deleted and you are querying for

```
SELECT  *
FROM    records
WHERE   isDeleted = 1
```

, the optimizer will choose the index, while for this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    records
WHERE   isDeleted = 0
```

it will use a full table scan.

If the number of neither deleted not retained records is below the tipping point (which depends on the record size and other things but as a rule of thumb can be considered `10%`), then the index will be probably never used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with MySQL you should use **BIT** datatype for this kind of operations regarding boolean checking and not integer. (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html).

**True** and **False** correspond to 1 an 0 respectively.

For those queries where you specify that the value is 1, an index on the column could be worthy, for 0, no. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215479/index-a-bit-field-in-mysql/5215503#5215503)